# Generating lognormal samples that fitts the data it was generated from

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, distribution

I'm trying to create a new sample based on some other samples but I'm doing/understanding something wrong. I have 34 samples which I assume is relatively lognorm distributed. Based on this samples I want to generate 2000 new samples. Here is the code that I'm running:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

samples = [480, 900, 1140, 1260, 1260, 1440, 1800, 1860, 1980, 2220, 2640, 2700,
           2880, 3420, 3480, 3600, 3840, 4020, 4200, 4320, 4380, 4920, 5160,
           5280, 6900, 7680, 9000, 10320, 10500, 10800, 15000, 21600, 25200,
           39000]
plt.plot(samples, 1 - np.linspace(0, 1, len(samples)))
std, loc, scale = stats.lognorm.fit(samples)
new_samples = stats.lognorm(std, loc=loc, scale=scale).rvs(size=2000)

a = plt.hist(new_samples, bins=range(100, 40000, 200),
             weights=np.ones(len(new_samples)) / len(new_samples))
plt.show()
```

Here is the plot, and as you can see there are really few samples above 1000, although the sample contained rather many above 1000.

[image: plot][image: Plot2]

How do I best generate a sample that better represent the expected values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something seems to be going wrong here with `stats.lognorm.fit`.

The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) mention an alternative by fitting `stats.norm` of the log of the samples and then using `exp(mu)` as scale. That seems to work a lot better.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

samples = [480, 900, 1140, 1260, 1260, 1440, 1800, 1860, 1980, 2220, 2640, 2700,
           2880, 3420, 3480, 3600, 3840, 4020, 4200, 4320, 4380, 4920, 5160,
           5280, 6900, 7680, 9000, 10320, 10500, 10800, 15000, 21600, 25200,
           39000]
samples = np.array(samples)

std, loc, scale = stats.lognorm.fit(samples) # 2.865850745357322, 479.99969879223596, 1.1400622824414484
weird_samples = stats.lognorm(std, loc=loc, scale=scale).rvs(size=2000)

mu, std = stats.norm.fit(np.log(samples)) # 8.304837454505837, 0.9720253999925554
scale = np.exp(mu) # 4043.3848507251523
loc = 0
new_samples = stats.lognorm(std, loc=loc, scale=scale).rvs(size=2000)

plt.plot(samples, 1 - np.linspace(0, 1, len(samples)), label='given samples')
plt.plot(np.sort(weird_samples), 1 - np.linspace(0, 1, len(weird_samples)), label='using stats.lognorm.fit(samples)')
plt.plot(np.sort(new_samples), 1 - np.linspace(0, 1, len(new_samples)), label='using stats.norm.fit(log(samples))')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Seaborn's kdeplot shows the following:

```py
import seaborn as sns

bw = 1500
sns.kdeplot(samples, bw=bw, label='given samples')
sns.kdeplot(weird_samples, bw=bw, label='using stats.lognorm.fit(samples)')
sns.kdeplot(new_samples, bw=bw, label='using stats.norm.fit(log(samples))')
plt.xlim(-5000, 45000)
plt.show()
```

[image: kdeplots]

PS: The problem seems to be that fitting 3 parameters using limited samples doesn't work very well. You can force `lognorm.fit` to use `loc=0`, which finds much more sensible parameters. The `loc` parameter just shifts the samples with that amount; often `loc=0` is the better choice.

```
std, loc, scale = stats.lognorm.fit(samples, floc=0) # 0.9720253999925554, 0.0, 4043.3848507251523
```

Instead of forcing `loc` with `floc`, you can also provide an initial guess. This looks even better:

```
std, loc, scale = stats.lognorm.fit(samples, loc=0) # 1.0527481074345748, 203.08004314932137, 3712.4903893865644
```

[image: fitting with initial guess]